# Django user model (user to user relation)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to ask more experienced coleagues about setting relations between users in standard django user model.

In my app I currently keep user data on 3 classes (User, Employee, Manager) as you can see on the below picture. 
[image]

I would like to simplify that model, but I'm not sure can I somehow do that on User class only. Is it possible to do something like this ?

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(models.Model): 
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="employees", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`"self"`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) string for this:

```
class User(models.Model): 
    manager = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="employees", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work. After migrating such model, django created new User table. I suppose it should add a new relational attribute in auth.User, but it didn't.